# CakePhp3 - Showing values on ChartJs

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, chart.js

I'm kinda new to CakePhP3 and I'm trying to generate some reports in ChartJs.

I have a table called "Incomes".

```
CREATE TABLE `incomes` (
 `id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `branch_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
 `amount` double NOT NULL,
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `comments` varchar(50000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And i want show to monthly generated total Income **amount** value on the Chart. Eg - January 10,000 , March 20,000.

```
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
var areaChartCanvas = $("#areaChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
// This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var areaChart = new Chart(areaChartCanvas);

var areaChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Electronics",
      fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }
  ]
};
```

How can i do load the **Incomes** model PagesController and show them on the chart? Do i send the values as JSON or what is the procedure?

Comment: Yes one of the possible approach would be sending JSON datas to the view. In CakePHP you can use serialize method for doing so. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: <?php echo json_encode($incomeTotal, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?> Found the way to turn it to JSON. How can filter out the amount's to the relevant months and display them?

Comment: @KasunWijesekara Search for `cakephp group by month` you will get the idea

Comment: @AgamBanga Thanks! Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

> In Controller

```
        $this->loadModel('Incomes');
        $incomes = $this->Incomes->find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'month',
            'valueField' => 'amount',
            'fields'=>[
                'month' => 'MONTHNAME(created)',
                'amount' => 'SUM(amount)'
            ],
            'group' => ['month'],
            'order'=>['MONTH(created)'=>'ASC'],
        ])->toArray();

        $months = json_encode(array_keys($incomes));
        $amounts = json_encode(array_values($incomes));
        $this->set('months', $months);
        $this->set('amounts', $amounts);
```

> In view

```
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
var areaChartCanvas = $("#areaChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
// This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var areaChart = new Chart(areaChartCanvas);

var areaChartData = {
  labels: <?= $months; ?>,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Electronics",
      fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: <?= $amounts; ?>
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Got it thanks. Helped me two times today! Thanks again.

Comment: any source i can look more in to this subject? :)

Comment: @KasunWijesekara For list check this link https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs